# Action Bar not showing because of Intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

**Update:**
I fix it by changing `MainActivityFragment extends FragmentActivity` to `MainActivityFragment extends AppCompatActivity`.

Thanks Guys.

The Action Bar will show if i don't comment the Intent. If I run the Intent in onCreate MainActivity, the Action Bar doesn't show. How do I show the Action Bar with the Intent. I provide the Intent (Main Activity) and Android Manifest code below.

Link to screenshot:

[Non-Intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98sK3.png)

[Intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLFwi.png)

MainActivity.java :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // this is the start     layout
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivityFragment.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.romi1.popularmoviesapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                info.movito
            </groupId>

            <artifactId>
                themoviedbapi
            </artifactId>

            <version>
                1.3
            </version>
        </dependency>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivityFragment"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MoviesDetailAdapter"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Style.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar-->
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

MainActivityFragment :

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        movies = new Movies[1000];

        jsonParser(json);

        moviesAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(this, movies);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        gridView.setAdapter(moviesAdapter);

        // This for setting what happen when one of the movie is selected
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                // Make another fragment class for this Adapter
                // And figure out away to send the clicked parcelable variable
                Movies topRatedMovieJson = moviesAdapter.getItem(i);
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "topRatedMovieJson : " + i);
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "topRatedMovieJson : " + topRatedMovieJson.title.toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MoviesDetailAdapter.class);
                intent.putExtra("parcelable", topRatedMovieJson);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I fix it by changing `MainActivityFragment extends FragmentActivity` to `MainActivityFragment extends AppCompatActivity`.

Thanks Guys.

Comment: I think you don't have actionBar in MainActivityFragment. Also it's quite confusing to have activity with name `MainActivityFragment`. May be you wanted to add fragment, not activity?

Comment: Thank Sergey. Sorry about the naming, I'l change it. The MainActivityFragment extends Fragment Activity. Could this be the cause? If it is, even though the theme of the app already been set up in the Android Manifest, I have to manually add the Action Bar to MainActivityFragment. Is this right?

Comment: can you show us your style.xml file

Comment: Thanks tk. I have add the style.xml. The The Class i try to Intent extends Fragment Activity. Could this be the cause as well?

Comment: Have you some code to hide actionBar in `MainActivityFragment` ?

Comment: Thanks Lionel. I have added the MainActivityFragment code. And I haven't mess with the ActionBar in the app before. I notice it's missing before, just now I'm trying to remedied the missing ActionBar. It happens when it run my Intent to MainActivityFragment extends FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do that 
1. Change that activity to fragment
2. Add Actionbar to second activity's layout and in your activity.

Comment: Thank tk. Does your second option means that adding it in the Android Manifest?

Comment: No, you have to make changes in your layout.xml file and in MainActivityFragment activity.. follow this example http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html

Comment: Thanks tk. I fix it by changing MainActivityFragment  extends Fragment Activity to AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can set two style and apply it to your activities.

describe style like this :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="SecondTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and apply it to activities :

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivityFragment" android:theme="@style/SecondTheme"/>
    <activity android:name=".MoviesDetailAdapter" android:theme="@style/SecondTheme"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Lionel. I fix it by changing MainActivityFragment extends Fragment Activity to AppCompatActivity.